# 0.8.2 Gephi fails to import Neo4j 2.0.1 database with trunk built Neo4j plugin

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I checked the GitHub project for Gephi's Neo4j plugins. They supposedly upgraded support for Neo4j 2.0.1 in the trunk. I attempted to build the plugins from source with these steps. I could not successfully import a 2.0.1 Neo4j DB, so I'm unsure if I missed something. Any thoughts on whether the plug-in source is the problem or if my steps are incorrect?

1. Install JDK 7 (if you have not already).
2. Ensure that JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the top-level JDK location on your machine.
3. Install Apache Ant.
4. Ensure that these 2 path variables for Ant have been set.
   a. Add the ANT_HOME environment variable set to C:\ant.
   b. Add the ANT_OPTS environment variable set to -Xmx256M.
5. Download the [Neo4j Gephi plug-in source code from GitHub](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/tree/72c15922c264b3594ecf396aa8518c384769b1fa)
6. Cd to your source directory with the Neo4j plug-in code for Gephi. Run this command:

   ```
   ant clean nbms
   ```
7. The build should be successful. Check the [your Gephi plug-in top-level]\build\updates for the constructed .nbm files.
8. Follow the [manual instructions](https://marketplace.gephi.org/how-to-install-a-plugin/) to install these plugins.
9. Open Gephi and go to File > Neo4j > Full import.  You should be able to view a Neo4j graph database of version 2.0.1.

Comment: Did you see any error messages? Can you share the gephi log files?

Comment: I did not see any error messages.  I actually tried the plug-in that was released on Gephi's Marketplace today (2014-03-04) and this problem has been fixed.  How should I close this question in that case?