# Gephi Neo4j Graph Database plugin

Tags: neo4j, database-connection, gephi

I have installed in Gephi 0.8.2 the Neo4j Graph Database plugin version 2.1.0. 
Neo4j Community 2.0.1 is running on my system (win7 64)

When I try to import a db (for example with the Full Import functionality, nothing happens after I select the DB, chose traversal options and go with the OK.

This question has already been published on the gephi forum but thought users here may be able to contribute and benefit from this question.

The latest release of the [Neo4j Gephi Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117695/0-8-2-gephi-fails-to-import-neo4j-2-0-1-database-with-trunk-built-neo4j-plugin) should support Neo4j 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your store is locked by another process, e.g. Neo4j server? In the neo4j store directory there should be no store.lock file.
The Traversal import in the neo4j plugin 2.1.0 suffers from a NotInTransaction-Exception, so be sure to use the full import or apply the not yet pulled [fix](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/issues/40) to the source.
Note as well that gephi will try to upgrade the datastore to 2.1.0, so work on a copy if you require the datastore not to be upgraded.